# Type default is not assignable to type ButtonLook clear

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, angular-kendo, kendo-angular-ui

I just started with Angular and when I tried to add a kendo button this error pops up:
*Type '"'default'"' is not assignable to type 'ButtonLook | "clear"'.*
In a fresh angular project first I used this command :

> ng add @progress/kendo-angular-buttons

Then,

> The package @progress/kendo-angular-buttons@6.3.0 will be installed and executed.

> Would you like to proceed? Yes
> ✔ Package successfully installed.

then I added a component.

> ng g c btn-control-panel

In btn-control-panel.component.html I tried this:

```
<div class="k-block">
    <button kendoButton look="'default'"></button>
</div>
```

On, compilation

> ng serve --o

It threw the following errors:

> Type '"'default'"' is not assignable to type 'ButtonLook | "clear"'.
> 2     
> ~~~~
> src/app/btn-control-panel/btn-control-panel.component.ts:5:16
> 5   templateUrl: './btn-control-panel.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component BtnControlPanelComponent.
> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
> ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
> 5 unchanged chunks
> Build at: 2021-09-08T04:41:31.525Z - Hash: 9d37dc75dd9c83801528 - Time: 221ms
> Error: src/app/btn-control-panel/btn-control-panel.component.html:2:25 - error TS2322: Type '"'default'"' is not assignable to type 'ButtonLook | "clear"'.
> 2     
> ~~~~
> src/app/btn-control-panel/btn-control-panel.component.ts:5:16
> 5   templateUrl: './btn-control-panel.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component BtnControlPanelComponent.

And, browser tab shows :

[image: Output in Browser]

Comment: As mentioned in [docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/buttons/api/ButtonDirective/), the `look` options are ButtonLook = flat | outline and `clear`. There is no option for `default`. You must use the provided option.

Comment: @YongShun it's working in stackbiltz with same version : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cs6lkt?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @shubham shaw Please try this: `<button kendoButton look="default"></button>` without single quote

Comment: Hi @Johar, I saw your project and didn't found *tsconfig.json*. This error will prompt out when in *tsconfig.json* with `compilerOptions: { "strict": true }`. This setting will enforce strict checking for entire Typescript project. You may refer [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict).

Comment: @YongShun https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/buttons/api/ButtonLook/ here is the docs which says it has "default" option

Comment: @YongShun it's confusing in their documentation. 'default' is only shown when we go into the details but not in the main page.

Comment: @Johar, yes `ButtonLook` has value of `default`. But in [ButtonDirective look](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/buttons/api/ButtonDirective/#toc-look), it only allows  the options for ButtonLook = flat | outline and `clear`.

Comment: @YongShun got it. Thanks